# write new line to file

Tags: abap

I'm trying to write to file newline. I'm using **WS_DOWNLOAD** but have no idea how to write new line into text.

Anyone knows ?

Comment: Stop using `WS_DOWNLOAD` - it's explicitly marked as obsolete - and start using `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_DOWNLOAD` in the first place :-)

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a character type field to `cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf` and insert that in the appropriate places (wherever you want a new line) to your output.

This contains the carriage return & linefeed characters.

Comment: thanks @Balthus. I was Looking for this easy answer for an hour.

Comment: It's only easy when you know the answer :)